# Why does datepicker highlight not work when I use "=="?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, reference

```
   .Highlighted a{
   background-color : Green !important;
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   font-size: 9pt;

}


  $(document).ready(function () {

                var date1 = new Date(2014, 5, 6);
                var date2 = new Date(2014, 5, 17);

                $('#datepicker').datepicker({

                   dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",

                   beforeShowDay: function (date) {


                       if (date == date1 ) {

                            return [true, 'Highlighted', 'Available Date'];
                        }
                        return [false, '', ''];
                    }
                });
        });
```

This one doesn't work, because of `date==date1`. If I change it to `date<=date1`, it works fine. I thought javascript is a weakly typed language and it compares the content, rather than reference.  I don't wanna do something like `(date.getDay==date1.getDay &&....)`. Is there an easier way to compare the values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5AYC/)

Use the `+` unary operator ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)) to convert the values to numerics for comparison.

> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.

---

```
if (+date === +date1 ) {

      return [true, 'Highlighted', 'Available Date'];
}
```

OR

```
if (!(date - date1)) {

      return [true, 'Highlighted', 'Available Date'];
}
```

Comment: This essentially does what the other answer does, however I find the other answer easier to read. Plus, someone new to JavaScript wouldn't know what the heck is being done with the plusses.

Comment: @j08691, i know, its just that I had solved the same problem using '+' some time before.

Comment: @j08691 I'd argue that someone new to javascript isn't going to look at `getTime()` and know that it means _"seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC"_ rather than _"the time portion of a date"_. `valueOf()` seems more attractive... but still not great.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript) you want to use the following to compare dates:

```
date.getTime() == date1.getTime()
```

Comment: This has the same effect as `+date`, but is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
if (date.valueOf() == date1.valueOf())
```